# Shell script to cleanup specified docker containers using grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep, docker, sh

I want to write a script that is executed by my development build server that will remove any 'similar' docker containers before building and running a new container.

Below is pseudo code for the bash script I need

```
var name = $1
var number_of_results = # of containers returned from $(docker ps -a | grep "$name")

if(number_of_result > 0)
      docker rm -f $(docker ps -a | grep "$name")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use this script in shell:

```
name="${1?one argument needed}"

ids=$(docker ps -a | awk -v name="$name" '$NF ~ name{print $1}')
[[ -n $ids ]] && docker rm -f $ids
```

Comment: is there a way to make this so that the name has to match exactly?

Comment: Yes sure: `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a | awk -v name="$name" '$NF == name{print $1}')`

Comment: Thank you for this. The only real problem I am having is that if it doesn't find a match, it fails, so I need to find a way to make it fail silently. Thanks